# adding interaction to GEE - model matrix is rank deficient

Tags: r

I am trying to run a GEE model, using geepack. I have done this successfully, using the below call.

```
Call:
geeglm(formula = pdc1 ~ country + post + time_post +
    TIME + age + sex + country * time_post + country * post, family = gaussian("identity"), data = lipid_data, 
    id = id, waves = ID, corstr = "ar1", std.err = "san.se").
```

where:

```
pdc1=numeric
country=factor
post=factor
time_post=numeric
TIME=numeric
```

I'm trying to run the exact same model on different data, which are in the exact same format as above. I can run the model with main effects, but not with the interactions. this is the error I get:

```
Error in geeglm(pdc1 ~ STATE + post + time_post + TIME + STATE * post,  : 
  Model matrix is rank deficient; geeglm can not proceed
```

I have tried recoding STATE as a numeric variable (and post) but this does not prove fruitful. I don't understand whats going on, the variables hold the exact same data as the first model, and are coded the way. Does anyone know what could be going on here?

Comment: Have you [thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Hi Henrik - yes i had a look, but am open to correction

Comment: If i have missed something obvious, I would be grateful if you could direct me there? In which case, I would also offer my apologies for inadvertently duplicating a question.

Comment: You probably are trying to estimate too many parameters with too few data points. How many parameters and data points are in your example? It is *very difficult* to provide a thorough answer without a reproducible example. I suggest you look up rank deficiency: ie http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it

Comment: Hi Nate - thank you for coming back to me, and giving me some direction. I have 8 parameters(inc interaction terms) and 67000 rows of data for about 6000 people. I could give a dput if thats of any use?

Answer (score 4):

I have recently solved a similar problem - it related to having one of the covariates constant across the dataset. For example, STATE might be the same state for each observation which may be causing the error "rank deficient". This might also explain why this error is specific to your new dataset.

Comment: I had the same problem: one of the `country` category had only one value of `post`, thus the rank deficient problem. When removing the `country` with only one value of `post` and dropping these levels, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you encountered the same problem as mine. I used to fit a geeglm model in R and got the same problem.

My model is something like:

```
geeglm(outCC$counts~outCC$partage:as.factor(outCC$contage)-1,
      family=poisson(link="log"),id=outCC$partid,data=outCC,subset=sel,weights=outCC$partwe)
```

This model runs without any problem.
However, when I tried to put another binary covariates setting (Urban/Rural) into the model:

```
geeglm(outCC$counts~outCC$partage:as.factor(outCC$contage)+as.factor(setting)-1,
       family=poisson(link="log"),id=outCC$partid,data=outCC,subset=sel,weights=outCC$partwe)
```

R gave me the error:

```
Model matrix is rank deficient; geeglm can not proceed
```

Then I decided to create a new binary variable: setting_new (0/1) and put this new variable in the mode:

```
geeglm(outCC$counts~outCC$partage:as.factor(outCC$contage)+setting_new-1,
       family=poisson(link="log"),id=outCC$partid,data=outCC,subset=sel,weights=outCC$partwe)
```

And now the problem is solved.

I got the same problem when trying to put another categorical variables into the above mentioned model, with the syntax:

```
as.factor(Q12_travel)
```

And the model could not run until I tried to create new dummy variables (0/1) and put it back to the model.
Maybe you have another problem, but I suggest you can try this approach to see if the problem is solved.